# Find previous or next array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, record

I created a rails app that allows the user to read a magazine.

To do so, I created two scaffolds, one for the magazine and an other for the pages inside of it. I then made a one-to-many relationship, so the pages belong to the magazine.

Each page is an image, since they are digitized then uploaded in a multi-upload form.

Recently, the group I work for asked me to find a way to allow the user to read two pages at the same time, so I made some tweaks, and it works like a charm.

However, I now have a problem: I want to set some "previous" and "next" links, but I can't find a way to do so

Here is what I have done so far:

**magazine_controller.rb**

```
  def create
    @magazine = Magazine.new(magazine_params)

    if @magazine.save
      @index = 0
      (params[:images] || []).each_with_index do |image, index|
        if index.even?
          #This way, @index increments every other upload
          #So I'm sure I have two images with the same page_number
          @index += 1
        end
        @magazine.pages.create(image: image, page_number: @index)
      end
      redirect_to @magazine, notice: 'Magazine créé'
    else
      render :new
    end
  end
```

**models/page.rb**

```
class Page < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :magazine
  validates_presence_of :magazine
  mount_uploader :image, PageUploader

  def previous
    self.class.first.where('page_number < ?', page_number).limit(1).first
  end

  def next
    self.class.first.where('page_number > ?', page_number).limit(1).last
  end

end
```

**views/pages/show.html.erb**

```
<% @page.each do |p| %>
  <%= image_tag p.image %>
  <%= p.inspect %>
<% end %>

<br />

<%= @page.first.page_number %>

<%= link_to '< Précédent', magazine_page_path(magazine_id: @magazine.slug, id: @page.previous) if @page.previous %>
<%= link_to 'Suivant >', magazine_page_path(magazine_id: @magazine.slug, id: @page.next) if @page.next %>
<br />
<%= link_to 'Back', magazines_path %>
```

**page_controller.rb**

```
  private
  def set_page
    @magazine = Magazine.find_by(slug: params[:magazine_id])
    #was 'find_by' before I was asked to show two records at the same time
    @page = @magazine.pages.where(page_number: params[:id])
  end
```

So with this code, I'm getting the error `undefined method 'previous' for #<Page::ActiveRecord_AssociationRelation:0x007ff4f702ad48>`. I don't have a clue about how to find if there is a following "page" or not.

Any idea welcome!

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

Remember that `@page` is no longer a single record, it's an association with two records.

You can create `previous` and `next` page methods in `Page` class for the association instead of the object (`self.previous` instead of `previous`). It will get a new association for the previous (or next) page number. Note the addiitional code to make sure you're getting the same magazine (which you don't have in your current code that worked for single pages).

Also note that if the association has no records (count == 0) the methods return `nil`... this is to accommodate your `if @page.previous` test for no previous (and `if @page.next` if no next)

```
def self.previous
  new_page_set = Page.where(page_number: (first.page_number - 1), magazine: first.magazine)
  return new_page_set.count == 0 ? nil : page_set
end

def self.next
  new_page_set = Page.where(page_numberL (first.page_number + 1), magazine: first.magazine)
  return new_page_set.count == 0 ? nil : page_set
end
```

Comment: Sorry it took so long to reply, I tried your code and it now says that `undefined local variable or method 'page_set'`, shouldn't it be "new_page_set" ?

Comment: So, it "works" (I no longer have errors), however my links are not showing up, it seems that it can't find anything before and after while I know it there is something

Comment: ok, put a `binding.pry` line just after `self.next` (this assumes you've got pry in your project... `gem 'pry'`)  and when it renders the page the console will stop at that method.  Take a look at the existing pages (`self` should show them) and check out the various fields... `first.magazine` and `first.page_number` and see if the values make sense.  Try doing manually `Page.where(page_number: 2, magazine_id: (id of the magazine object)`  It's all standard debugging...